# <div> won't overlap img with z-index

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type, owl-carousel

I have trouble getting my div to overlap the next div using z-index.

The main purpose of this function will be the orange box containing a introduction of the person on the picture on the left of the orange box.
But the box won't overlap the div you're seeing to it's right.

[Click to see what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq5ww.png)

```
<div class="holder">
 <div class="member">
   <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
   <div class="content-member">
      <!-- <h3><?php the_field('name'); ?></h3>
      <span><?php the_field('function'); ?></span>
      <div class="skills"><?php the_field('skills'); ?></div> -->
   </div>
```

Here's my html (it loops automatically so that's why there are multiple on the image I included. In this example .holder and .member aren't closed off because it wouldn't let it fit or something.

```
.member {
float:left;
position: relative;
top:194px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index:5;

.content-member {
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  float: left;
  background-color: $c-orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left:180px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 500;
}

img {
  height:40vh;
  width:auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

&:hover {
  .content-member {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

And here's the css I'm using right now.

I can't get this figured out..

Comment: It's scss for the record, not css.

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once Using With Keyframes

```css
.main{
width:300px;
height:200px;
position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
.overed-div{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:310px;
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ff8800;
  z-index:2;
  text-align:center;
  opacity:0;
  
}
.main img:hover+ .overed-div {
  animation-name: details;
  animation-duration: 1.5s; 
  opacity:1;
}
@keyframes details{
from{opacity:0;}
to{opacity:1;}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/82/ad/c6/82adc661b9a9b0d2cdaa9c61d29ae4a0.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%;"/>
 <div class="overed-div"><h2>Nature</h2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't the issue tho. The div does become visible but it doesn't overlap the img to it's right